# Unable to publish to facebook feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, html, facebook-opengraph

I operate a website, http://www.plingo.com.br/

I have created a like button for that webpage, as well as specified opengraph tags that point back to the same URL and included a video.

I have set the og:type tag to 'blog'.

When someone clicks Like, the video and URL get posted to the users feed as expected.
However, my issue revolves around being able to publish to users of my feed.

As you can see in my opengraph tags, I have associated my URL to a facebook application that I own.

I have followed the instructions at developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ on how to publish to my feed directly, however when I run the PHP script, I receive this error:

```
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) (the url) does not resolve to a valid user ID",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
```

However, the opengraph at the URL points both to my facebook account as well as my application.

I have no idea why I am unable to do this.

However, to try to diagnose the issue, I made a similar webpage at http://www.plingo.com.br/ogtest.php and set all the attributes of the opengraph tags the same, except for the og:url and the youtube video. Running the publish script using that URL however, works fine, and facebook even generated an administrative page for publishing to facebook.

I am wondering why this is not working with my root URL. Is there any way to get Facebook to give me an Administrative Page? Why can't I publish, even though I have associated the opengraph IDs properly?

I would GREATLY appreciate any input as I have tried countless different things, changes, etc to see where the issue lies.

Thank you

Comment: I've checked further, and when I put both the above mentioned URLs into the graph api (https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.plingo.com.br/) and (https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.plingo.com.br/ogtest.php), and the latter appears to be a Node in the graph, while the former isn't. 

I'm thinking it may be related to this: (http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13092)

I discovered this through: (http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=78701)

and 

(http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=269591#p269591)

Comment: Did you figure anything else out here? I'm having a similar issue